# What is the difference between these video codecs?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, codec

I'm familiar with general digital video formats, but I'm trying to record my first Patreon videos - which are long (59min) and I'm finding myself completely baffled by format filesizes. I could really use some clarification!

I'm using OBS Studio to record approximately 1 hour of Photoshop footage, with narration, in .FLV format (OBS's native record format). Then, I'm using VLC player to convert the footage from FLV to MP4. Then, I'm importing the footage into OpenShot video editor to add titles, credits, etc and finalize the footage for upload to YouTube.

My file sizes make *no* sense. That is, the output file from OpenShot is ridiculously large no matter what format I choose, and I'm stumped. I'd use the OpenShot forums, but there's no way to *register*.

The file sizes and codecs are the following:

Original recording via OBS Studio: 59 min/60fps//VLC/h264 - mpeg-4 avc (part 10) (avc1)/219 MB

VLC conversion to MP4: 59 min/60fps/MP4/h264 - mpeg-4 avc (part 10) (avc1)/184 MB

OneShot edited video output: 59:49 min/30FPS/MP4/MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)/2.6 GB

Now, I'm still pretty newbie to H264 and MP4 codecs, but why in the name of god do I have two programs (OBS Studio and VLC player) outputting a 59min60fps video with complete clarity at ~200MB, while the LOWEST filesize I can get with OpenShot at only *30* fps is 2.6 GB??  I tried everything I could do with a bunch of different formats, but that's the lowest it goes. Not to mention, it takes 5 *hours*to render the video out.  Help!

Comment: Looks like the forum is dead, no posts for a month now.

Comment: The file size is directly affected by the 'Data Rate' value. The higher the Data Rate the higher the file size will be. Sounds to me like whatever OpenShot preset you're using to convert the video has a ridiculously high data rate to make sure all quality is preserved to HD level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The odd thing is, if I set the OpenShot output to even something crappy, like Low Quality, it still makes an enormous file (~+800MB). OBS Studio’s output files - the raw record footage - must have an amazingly low data rate and yet every frame at 60fps is clean. There’s something happening that I’m not grasping. Is OpenShot’s codec just that terrible?

Comment: your final output is uncompressed video.